# Hours in a month - mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, hour

I have this query that meant to calculate hours
Hours for the month including the current month to date as on this hour
Is there a more effecient way of writing this query ?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at), '%Y-%m') as month,
     CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at), '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m')
     THEN (DAYOFMONTH(NOW())*24)+ HOUR(NOW()) + (MINUTE(NOW())/60) + (SECOND(NOW())/3600) 
     ELSE DAY(LAST_DAY(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at), '%Y-%m-%d')))*24
     END As hours
  FROM table1 
 GROUP 
     BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at), '%Y-%m')
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Do you need to or have you considered daylight saving?

Comment: No need to consider daylight saving

Answer (score 0):

You could use specific mysql date and time function as

```
  SELECT month(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at)) as month,
        CASE WHEN month(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at)) = month(now())
                THEN  TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01'),NOW()) 
                ELSE HOUR(LAST_DAY(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at), '%Y-%m-%d')))
  END As hours
  FROM table1 
  GROUP BY month(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at))
```